# What argument does contract.GetFunctionSignature expects?

Tags: solidity, nethereum

I'm trying to get function by signature from contract using `Nethereum.Contracts.Contract.GetFunctionBySignature`.
This function seems to expect the signature of function, however how can I generate the function signature appropriate for the above method?
For example, there's a function like this... `function F(bool by) public {}`

and I tried for the signature of this function by ...

- `F(bool)`
- GenerateSha3Signature ("F", [| boolParam |])
  and none of them succeeded to find the function. What the hell this method expects for the argument?
  Thanks, waiting for the precious answers.